# Is it posssible to link an obj file compiled using visual studio 2008 by the linker of visual studio 2010 or 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, linker

I am compiling a .cpp file using cl.exe of visual studio 2008. I want it linked using link.exe of any version of visual studio. When I do it, I get some link errors for _Xran, _Xlen etc. Is there any ways to acheive compatibility of .obj file?

Comment: Technically yes.  But you'll have to stop using the standard C++ template classes and take control of the application manifest.